# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in position 0: not in ordinal range (128)

Tags: python, ascii, python-unicode

I have a hex string represented as a list of single characters that contains some text. When I try to decode the hex with:

```
for counter, i in enumerate(hexadecimal):
    if counter % 2 == 0:
        pass
    else:
        temp_list = hexadecimal[counter:counter + 2]
        hex_string = ''.join(str(x) for x in temp_list)
        bytes_string = bytes.fromhex(hex_string)
        ascii_text += bytes_string.decode('ascii')
```

It works fine but when it encounters the number ['A', 7] it gives me this error.
I assume it's because the character doesn't exist in ASCII, how do I make a readable character from that?

EDIT:

An example input would be `[6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 3]` which yields `abc` as output.

A program input is `[0, 'F', 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 'E', 3, 0, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3, 4, 3, 7, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1]` which yields `40.01V 4723AA3Q`

Comment: Why do you call `decode('ascii')` to begin with? Strings in Python 3 are Unicode. You need to identify what encoding is used in `hexadecimal` and use *that* to convert the bytes to text. If the encoding is UTF8, use 'utf-8` as the encoding

Comment: On the other hand, what is `hexadecimal`? What does it contain, where did it come from? Couldn't you read the actual string directly from the file or HTTP response this came from? Storing text as a hex string instead of actual text is **very** unusual - it actually takes more space than just storing the string itself. Is `hexadecimal` a BASE64 string perhaps?

Comment: hexadecimal contains a series of characters that represent a hexadecimal like ['A', 5, 6, 'D', 3, 4] and I don't know which encoding is used I only get those values as hexadecimal, but ASCII yields the right results until I get the error

Comment: @AlePan No it doesn't. If it did, you'd get an error like this: "ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1". Please edit your question and show some **real example input** for `hexadecimal` that produces the error you say you are getting, and also state clearly what output you expect to get.

Comment: A7 is not a valid ASCII character, period. Perhaps it represents a character in Latin-1, or one of the other myriad encodings. But not ASCII. Without knowing what A7 is *supposed* to represent, we can't give you a real answer.

Comment: Also, you can shorten all that to `bytes.fromhex(''.join(map(str, hexadecimal))).decode('ascii')`…

Comment: @AlePan If you remove the lines `pass` and `else:` your code will work (i.e. there's an off-by-one error). But note that the 2nd example will actually output `'\x0f40.01V 4723AA3Q'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to represent any byte as an acceptable character, you should use the Latin-1 or ISO-8859-1 encoding (2 names but same charset). Any byte is accepted, even if some are not printable characters. The representation is the unicode character of same value (up to 255 of course) if it exists.

For you question, `'\xa7'` will be the unicode character U+00A7 SECTION SIGN `§`.

So you just have to change your last line with:

```
ascii_text += bytes_string.decode('Latin1')
```

Comment: "Latin-1" is a somewhat informal name and depending on who you ask *can* differ slightly from ISO-8859-1. Moreover, it doesn't have to be Latin-1 at all, any single-byte encoding using 256 values will do…

Comment: @deceze: I do not agree. Latin1 is a true synonym of ISO-8859-1. I do not speak of its variants like Latin-9 (synonym of ISO-8859-15) of windows codepage 1252. And Latin1 has the unique feature to represent all unicode characters of code < 256 *with the same value*. You are true that any encoding using 256 values could be used, but without more context, I would advise it first.